# Trying to scrape a website with python3 and beautifulSoup, but getting an empty list back

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a simple script that prints the current price of bitcoins from the website: https://www.bitcoinprice.com/

```
#This is a script that returns the price of one Bitcoin in US dollars
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.bitcoinprice.com/"

#Get the url to beautifulSoup format
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)

#get the price
element = soup.select("#price")
```

When I try to print the "element" variable I get this:

```
<span id="price" style="font-size: 72px; font-weight: bold;"></span>
```

I believe this is caused by the JavaScript on the page. Is there a better way to get the price from the website?

Comment: The price is likely shown on-screen by the minified js function, as you have suggested. It would be very time-consuming to try and reverse engineer it, in order to extract its relevant inputs and recompute the function in python. Would you accept as a solution the extraction of the current price of bitcoin from other sources, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right here. The value is being constantly updated by Javascript and is not captured by the `Scrapper`.

I would recommend you to use the backend API that the website is using for collecting the data.

There is an open API which you can hit after a certain amount of time (let's say 1 minute) and get the data directly instead of scrapping.

**`GET https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD&e=CCCAGG`**

The JSON response is below,

```
{
    "RAW": {
        "BTC": {
            "USD": {
                "TYPE": "5",
                "MARKET": "CCCAGG",
                "FROMSYMBOL": "BTC",
                "TOSYMBOL": "USD",
                "FLAGS": "4",
                "PRICE": 6544.82,
                "LASTUPDATE": 1539801288,
                "LASTVOLUME": 0.004,
                "LASTVOLUMETO": 25.74948,
                "LASTTRADEID": "52589962",
                "VOLUMEDAY": 27152.289698759938,
                "VOLUMEDAYTO": 178354574.93607947,
                "VOLUME24HOUR": 38151.0738459291,
                "VOLUME24HOURTO": 250157534.15733647,
                "OPENDAY": 6582.86,
                "HIGHDAY": 6589.2,
                "LOWDAY": 6511.6,
                "OPEN24HOUR": 6541.77,
                "HIGH24HOUR": 6598.58,
                "LOW24HOUR": 6504.37,
                "LASTMARKET": "Coinbase",
                "CHANGE24HOUR": 3.0499999999992724,
                "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": 0.04662346734903967,
                "CHANGEDAY": -38.039999999999964,
                "CHANGEPCTDAY": -0.5778643325241607,
                "SUPPLY": 17327237,
                "MKTCAP": 113403647262.34,
                "TOTALVOLUME24H": 256273.81355038052,
                "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": 1677731603.429824
            }
        }
    },
    "DISPLAY": {
        "BTC": {
            "USD": {
                "FROMSYMBOL": "Ƀ",
                "TOSYMBOL": "$",
                "MARKET": "CryptoCompare Index",
                "PRICE": "$ 6,544.82",
                "LASTUPDATE": "Just now",
                "LASTVOLUME": "Ƀ 0.004000",
                "LASTVOLUMETO": "$ 25.75",
                "LASTTRADEID": "52589962",
                "VOLUMEDAY": "Ƀ 27,152.3",
                "VOLUMEDAYTO": "$ 178,354,574.9",
                "VOLUME24HOUR": "Ƀ 38,151.1",
                "VOLUME24HOURTO": "$ 250,157,534.2",
                "OPENDAY": "$ 6,582.86",
                "HIGHDAY": "$ 6,589.20",
                "LOWDAY": "$ 6,511.60",
                "OPEN24HOUR": "$ 6,541.77",
                "HIGH24HOUR": "$ 6,598.58",
                "LOW24HOUR": "$ 6,504.37",
                "LASTMARKET": "Coinbase",
                "CHANGE24HOUR": "$ 3.05",
                "CHANGEPCT24HOUR": "0.05",
                "CHANGEDAY": "$ -38.04",
                "CHANGEPCTDAY": "-0.58",
                "SUPPLY": "Ƀ 17,327,237.0",
                "MKTCAP": "$ 113.40 B",
                "TOTALVOLUME24H": "Ƀ 256.27 K",
                "TOTALVOLUME24HTO": "$ 1,677.73 M"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `PRICE` key holds the coressponding data that you need.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. :)

Comment: open browser console, under network tab you'll be able to see the API XHR hits.